# how to pass value to view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a 2 view model, FacilityInRoomViewModel and NewRoomViewModel, how can i pass value to NewRoomViewModel from FacilityInRoomViewModel in controller with service??

this my view model

```
namespace XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel
{
    public class FacilityInRoomViewModel
    {
        public int RoomFacilityID { get; set; }
        public string RoomFacilityName { get; set; }
        public bool RoomFacilityAvailable { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListFacilityInRoom
    {
        public List<FacilityInRoomViewModel> listRoomFacility { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel
{
    public class NewRoomViewModel
    {
        public int HotelID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string RoomTypeName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string RoomTypeDescription { get; set; }

        public List<FacilityInRoomViewModel> facilityinRoom { get; set; }
    }

}
```

my viewModelBuilder Class

```
namespace XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.Builder
{
    public class FacilityInRoomBuilder
    {
        public static ListFacilityInRoom Build(List<RoomFacility> roomFacility)
        {
            ListFacilityInRoom model = new ListFacilityInRoom();
            model.listRoomFacility = new List<FacilityInRoomViewModel>();

            foreach (var roomFacilities in roomFacility)
            {
                FacilityInRoomViewModel t = new FacilityInRoomViewModel
                {
                    RoomFacilityID = roomFacilities.RoomFacilityID,
                    RoomFacilityName = roomFacilities.RoomFacilityName,
                    RoomFacilityAvailable = roomFacilities.IsActive
                };
                model.listRoomFacility.Add(t);
            }
            return model;
        }

        public static NewRoomViewModel Build2(List<FacilityInRoomViewModel> list)
        {
            NewRoomViewModel model = new NewRoomViewModel();
            model.facilityinRoom = list;

            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

my service

```
public List<RoomFacility> showNewRooms()
        {
            List<RoomFacility> showNewRoomViewModel = _RoomFacilityRepository.AsQueryable().ToList();
                return showNewRoomViewModel;
        }
```

my controller

```
    public ActionResult NewRoom()
            {
                var showNewRoomViewModel = _RoomTypeService.showNewRooms();
                ListFacilityInRoom model = FacilityInRoomBuilder.Build(showNewRoomViewModel);
return View(model);

            }
```

Comment: Hi novian, I would rename the variables a bit to to make the example code more clear. For example, var showNewRoomViewModel is not one of the two ViewModels you mentioned. Also, the model passed into the View() method should be a ViewModel.

Comment: can you give me example?? please

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have it lloks like you are trying to pass FacilityInRoomViewModel to the

```
public static NewRoomViewModel Build2(List<FacilityInRoomViewModel> list)
    {
        NewRoomViewModel model = new NewRoomViewModel();
        model.facilityinRoom = list;

        return model;
    }
```

but in  NewRoomViewModel you are expecting to have just an object of List

i think in your

```
 public ActionResult NewRoom()
 {
     var showNewRoomViewModel = RoomTypeService.showNewRooms();
     ListFacilityInRoom model = FacilityInRoomBuilder.Build(showNewRoomViewModel);
     var newroomviewmodel=FacilityInRoomBuilder.Build2(showNewRoomViewModel.listRoomFacility);
     return View(newroomviewmodel);
  }
```

Comment: then i do not really get your question

Comment: i have two viewmodel, and i want to pass value from one viewmodel to another viewmodel from my controller.

Comment: i cant pass value to build2 from my controller.

Comment: cannot convert newRoomViewModel to ListFacilityInRoom

Comment: when i pass value from facilitiesInRoom to NewRoom

Comment: can you give part in yourr sample